# Hosting Angular2 on Heroku

Tags: heroku, typescript, angular

I am having trouble finding a tutorial on how to host an angular2 application (hopefully with Typescript) on Heroku or any other hosting provider for that matter.

Ideally, I'd like to find a way to run this repo on Heroku but guidance on any angular2/typescript repo on Heroku would be helpful: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-authentication-sample

Any guidance or advise you can offer would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You will need server app/framework for that.

This repository contains files from Express generator app and Quick-start Angular 2 app.

- Git: https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-slim
- Heroku demo: https://express-angular2-slim.herokuapp.com/

---

I have one other example that is also ready for Heroku: express + angular 2 + Procfile ( needed by the Heroku ) + other libraries

- Git: https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter
- Heroku demo: https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter

You need an account on Heroku. Push this code as-is ( in both cases ).

---

Official repo from Angular2 ( server side rendering ) on Express:
https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

Comment: I ran into errors when trying to deploy your repo to Heroku. Please see my terminal error here in the edit note above:

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Comment: There were error in dependencies, please pull again from git and build. I already tried, demo app is here: https://express-angular2.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I improved my answer.

Comment: many thnx - I am very grateful and hope others find this helpful

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any problems or doubts, please contact me over GitHub. I removed error log from your answer. ;)

Comment: Is it possible to speed up the load time? It loads 600+ Node modules which takes 30-45 seconds (Sydney). Surely there is a better way to do it (merge + minification defeats the purpose of web components surely?), any guides?

Answer (score 3):

If you use Heroku's Node buildpack, I believe you should be fine. I was able to deploy the [Angular 2 seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) project to Heroku this way.

If you want to deploy a real, full-blown web application using Angular 2, you will almost certainly need some sort of persistence layer, like Vlado mentioned.

If you're interested in deploying Angular 2 to Heroku with Rails, here's a tutorial for that. https://www.angularonrails.com/deploy-angular-2rails-5-app-heroku/

Comment: It's true, you can deploy as-is with the Node.js buildpack.  In my case this is a perfect solution, since I'm hooking into a Rails API on a separate Heroku app

Answer (score 2):

Since Angular 2 moved from `systemjs` to `webpack`, in order to deploy app to Heroku you can build it with Node.js buildpack then serve it with static buildpack.

Here's my version of today's (Oct 24, 2016) Angular 2 seed made ready to deploy to Heroku using this approach: [heroku-angular2-seed](https://github.com/vassiliy/heroku-angular2-seed/).

Answer (score 1):

Ok I came up with a solution.  I had to add a very basic PHP backend, but it's pretty harmless.  Below is my process.

First setup a heroku app and Angular 2 app.

1. Create your heroku app
2. Set the heroku buildpack to heroku/php

   - `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php --app heroku-app-name`
3. Create a project via Angular-Cli
4. Add a index.php file to `/scr` with the below snippet

   `<?php include_once("index.html"); ?>`
5. Add a Procfile to `/scr` with the below snippet

   `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2`
6. Added `/deploy` to the .gitignore

Now I used a npm package to push a tarballs to heroku

1. Here's a simple package to upload the tarball, https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku-deploy-tarball

   - `npm i heroku-deploy-tarball --save`
2. I'm also using tar.gz to create the tarball

   - `npm i tar.gz --save`
3. Then I created the `deploy.js` file at the root of my projecdt with the following code.  I first run the buildCommand specified and then move the index.php and Profile to the dist folder.  I then tarball the entire dist folder and it gets uploaded to heroku.

---

```
var deploy = require('heroku-deploy-tarball');
var targz = require('tar.gz');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var requestedTarget = process.argv[2];

if (!requestedTarget) {
  console.log('You must specify a deploy target');
  return;
}

var targets = {
  production: {
    app: 'heroku-app-name',
    tarball: 'deploy/build.tar.gz',
    buildCommand: 'ng build --prod'
  }
}

var moveCompressFiles = function (callback) {
  exec('cp ./src/index.php ./dist/index.php',
    function(err) {
      if(err)
        console.log(err);
      console.log('index.php was copied.');
    });
  exec('cp ./src/Procfile ./dist/Procfile',
    function(err) {
      if(err)
        console.log(err);
      console.log('Procfile was copied.');
    });

  new targz().compress('./dist', './deploy/build.tar.gz',
    function(err){
      if(err)
        console.log(err);
      else
        callback();
      console.log('The compression has ended!');
    });
}

console.log('Starting ' + targets[requestedTarget].buildCommand);
exec(targets[requestedTarget].buildCommand, {maxBuffer: 1024 * 500}, function(error) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(targets[requestedTarget].buildCommand + ' successful!');
    moveCompressFiles(function () {
      deploy(targets[requestedTarget]);
    });
  } else {
    console.log(targets[requestedTarget].buildCommand + ' failed.', error);
  }
});
```

4. Now just run `node deploy production` and it should deploy to heroku.

---

### Heroku experimental build pack

Just got word from heroku that they are working on an experimental buildpack that would allow for static sites like this.  [Here is the link to the build pack.](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static)