# How to host angular2 app on heroku?

Tags: angular, hosting

I have to host some sample app on heroku built with angular2.

Also, Is there any generator available for scaffold angular2 app with gulp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need server app/framework for that.

This repository contains files from Express generator app and Quick-start Angular 2 app.

Git: https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-slim
Heroku demo: https://express-angular2-slim.herokuapp.com/
I have one other example that is also ready for Heroku: express + angular 2 + Procfile ( needed by the Heroku ) + other libraries

Git: https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter
Heroku demo: https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter
You need an account on Heroku. Push this code as-is ( in both cases ).

Official repo from Angular2 ( server side rendering ) on Express: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

Please refer answer of [Hosting Angular2 on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424790/hosting-angular2-on-heroku)